# .Net Standard project : System.Linq.Enumerable class missing

Tags: c#, linq, .net-standard

In .Net Standard 1.5 project(1.6 is installed from nuget).

I cannot use Extension methods of `Linq` that resides in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

like `Where`, `Select` methods on `LIST<string>`

I have already installed below packages:

```
"System.Linq": "4.3.0",
"System.Linq.Expressions": "4.3.0",
"System.Linq.Queryable": "4.3.0",
```

**Update**

Example:

```
using System.Linq;

List<string> myList = new List(); 
myList = // suppose list got data

myList.Where(  // Where is not available
```

**Note**

System.Linq.Enumerable static class containing Extension methods are not accessible.

**Update 2**

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Chance.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserInteraction": "1.1.4",
    "Fody": "1.29.4",
    "MethodDecorator.Fody": "0.9.0.6",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "MvvmCross": "4.3.0",
    "MvvmCross.Platform": "4.3.0",
    "NEST": "5.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "PropertyChanged.Fody": "1.52.1",
    "System.Linq": "4.3.0",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.3.0",
    "System.Linq.Queryable": "4.3.0",
    "System.ServiceModel": "1.0.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.3.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.3.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+netcore45+wp8"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a small code example? And a few shots in the dark: did you check if the library's are referenced, have you imported them with a "using" and are you calling them on a List object or are you trying to call them on the List class?

Comment: @prof1990 I am trying to access extension methods present in System.Linq.Enumerable class via object of List<T>. I have checked, System.Linq.Enumerable class is not available but the interesting thing is that System.Linq package is installed. Then which package is required for the extension methods.

Comment: Show your full `project.json`

Comment: I had this issue in an F# project in Visual Studio 2017 RC. I discovered the project was missing the reference, it was not available from "Add References" under either "Framework" or "Extensions", but I was able to find the official Microsoft Nuget via Package Manager and solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, following change in project.lock.json "fix" the problem:

```
"System.Linq/4.3.0": {
..
        "compile": {
          "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81/_._": {}
        },
..
      },
```

with

```
"System.Linq/4.3.0": {
..
        "compile": {
          "ref/netstandard1.0/System.Linq.dll": {}
        },
..
      },
```

There are few similar sections.
It is rather workaround than proper solution

Answer (score 0):

I forgot this question, the issue was resolved by adding a package that needs System.Linq dll. Unfortunately, I don't remember the package name and I have no longer access to that project. But any body facing such issue may try some packages that starts with System.Linq.*